# File wont get saved in server, what to do?

Tags: php, mysql

I've created a website where you upload pictures/files to a server and the database saves the place where the file is placed. Everything gets saved in the database but the file won't get saved in my server, what to do?

```
<?php 


$target = "bilder/"; 
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']); 

$name=$_POST['name'];  
$desc=$_POST['desc']; 
$pic=($_FILES['photo']['name']); 

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error()) ; 
mysql_select_db("david") or die(mysql_error()) ; 

mysql_query("INSERT INTO `bild` VALUES ('$name', '$desc', '$pic', NOW())") ; 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
{ 

echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']). " was uploaded! <br>"; 
echo "Click " . '<a href="bilder.php">here</a>' . " to see all uploaded files<br>";
echo "Click " . '<a href="test.html">here</a>' . " to upload more files!";
} 

else { 
echo "Error."; 
} 
?>
```

Comment: your application (user) probably has not enough rights to access the directory or the directory does not exist, also please note that $_FILES is an array: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Comment: code would print “Error” or  "Click......."?

Comment: How can I change the rights?

Comment: put your `bilder` directory permission to `777`.. using `chmod` in command prompt..

Comment: DO you have error message when you run this code if so please post.

Comment: and if you are using `windows` just right click on the folder, go to `properties` and `uncheck` `readonly`..

Comment: Changed the rights to 777 in WinSCP and now it works! Thanks for the help

Comment: In development environment, open display_errors in php.ini, you will get errors easily. a warnning/error will told you how to fix.

Answer (score 1):

Probably permission denied, Open the "display_errors=On" in php.ini file, you may get a warning message.

try to `"chmod 777 bilder/"`

Comment: I changed it to 777 and now it works for me to upload pictures/files to the server, but I tried it on another computer and it wont work, any thoughts?

Comment: @user3327442 you'd better open the display_error, check what's the really reasons. a simple way to open display_errors switch: `ini_set("display_errors", 0);` at the beginning of code. Then, you will get some message, post these messages may help us.

Comment: so I should type  "ini_set("display_errors", 0);" outside the php tags?

Comment: If I put it at the top of my code it does nothing, still output the same error message. but if i replace the normal error message with " ini_set("display_errors", 0);" it outputs "0"

Comment: Sorry,Sorry,my fault!`ini_set("display_errors", 1); `~~~I mean DO display errors. 0 will colsed display.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that enctype attribute was added to the form submitting this to the processing script.

Do a var_dump of $_FILES['photo']['name'] to be sure the file was sent to your processing too.